# HTML div value not showing

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have variable which when i show in alert it shows values 1 but when i assign that value to div then it does not show value on page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script >


        var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
        var con=document.getElementById('data');
        var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
            //$("data").html(v);
            return v == 'b' ? i : null;
        });
        //con.innerHTML=inds;

        alert(inds); // 0,3,6

        var avr1=inds;
        con.innerHTML=avr1;
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran this code and it put `1` in data div

Comment: You should run it within a document.ready to be sure that the element exsists before trying to access it

Comment: @DeadMan i mean that it show 1 in alert and also in div on web page

Comment: @lesusSonesson can you write please all code how it may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="data"></div>
        <script>


            var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
            var con=document.getElementById('data');
            var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
                return v == 'b' ? i : null;
            });

            alert(inds); // 0,3,6

            var avr1=inds;
            con.innerHTML=avr1;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer of Sudhir is right. you should put the script at the end of body.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
    var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
        return v == 'b' ? i : null;
    });

    $('#data').html(inds.join(','));
});
```

I've just updated my answer. See a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eJbaT/3/)

Comment: It would have worked if you would have included the latest `jQuery`. The code is already fine. http://jsfiddle.net/eJbaT/5/

Comment: @ShahzadAli I just added an answer. Check that

Answer (score 0):

as you are using jQuery, wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() ..`, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
   var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
      return v == 'b' ? i : null;
  });
  $("#data").html(inds);
});
```

or add that script at end of your `body` tag
See: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eJbaT/2/)

Comment: @ShahzadAli that's what i am saying to the guy who answered.

Comment: @ShahzadAli update to latest jQuery version and it should work fine

Comment: @DeadMan thanks can you please help pe out this and edit in jsfiddle please

Comment: @ShahzadAli see added Demo jsfiddle link in my updated answer

Comment: @Sudhir check this link http://jsfiddle.net/eJbaT/8/ this is variable what i want but it doen not show

Comment: @ShahzadAli the variable inside $.map is asigned to index of the array if 'b' is found and is returned to your outer variable inds, so it contains index of 'b' which is 1

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine.I had check it.

```
 <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script >

        var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
        var con=document.getElementById('data');
        var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
            return v == 'b' ? i : null;
        });
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML=inds;
 </script>
```

Comment: not working where you have check can you give link of jsfiddle